# how to have undeletable words(part of text) in textarea 

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am developing an application which needs a part of text in the textarea undeletable while they can add their text to the `textarea`.

For example when user come to a web page it has a textarea which has a text `{username}` of that user. The user can add more text like `{username} hi the the earth is globe` but should be unable to delete `{username}` from that textarea.

I am using Jquery as the javascript class, any idea that we can achieve it in Jquery?

Comment: Although your question makes sense, I think you going down the hardest path

Comment: Perhaps using the HTML5 Canvas to render the immutable text and editing the default carat position would accomplish this, but I agree with Luis in that it would be more practical to go about this some other way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this would be to perform a validation to make sure they didn't delete `{username}`, and display an error message (maybe auto-insert `{username}` at the beginning of the textarea as well) if they did.

However I agree with Luis that this is a difficult route to take. What about just displaying their username in a readonly field and giving them a textarea to add their own content to be displayed after it?

Comment: nice idea.. but I am working out something cool.. I will keep u guys posted if my result is positive :P

Answer (score 1):

Not sure at all but I got this and it still need to be improved a lot

```
<script>

$(function (){
    $('#txtarea').keyup(function (){check()});
})

var txt = "username"; 
//txt is reg exp

function check(){
    var txtarea = $('#txtarea');
    var val = $(txtarea).val();

    if(val.match('^'+txt)){
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        $(txtarea).val(txt+" "+val);
    }
}
</script>
<textarea id="txtarea">username</textarea>
<a href="#"  onclick="check()">check</a>
```

**[UPDATE]**

```
<script>

$(function (){
    $('#txtarea').keyup(function (){check()});
})

var txt = "username"; 
//txt is reg exp

function check(){
    var txtarea = $('#txtarea');
    var val = $(txtarea).val();

    if(val.match('^'+txt)){
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //this is quite a bit flawed
        //and i m terrible with regex
        //do try to become creative
        val = val.replace('usernam', '');
        val = val.replace('userna', '');
        val = val.replace('usern', '');
        val = val.replace('user', '');
        val = val.replace('use', '');
        val = val.replace('us', '');
        val = val.replace('u', '');

        $(txtarea).val(txt+" "+val);
    }
}
</script>
<textarea id="txtarea">username</textarea>
<a href="#"  onclick="check()">check</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're text would be positioned in fixed front or end, I found a solution for each.

Fixed front: [How to lock the first word of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704795/how-to-lock-the-first-word-of-a-textarea)

Fixed end: [How to have a disabled text in textarea-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464697/how-to-have-a-disabled-text-in-textarea-like/11464748#11464748)

Cheers!